# Moving the ELF64 relocation table

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, elf, relocation

I'm attempting to move the `.rela.plt` relocation table of a shared object to the end of the file (Because I'm going to add new relocation entries in the future).

First, I read all entries in the `.rela.plt` section. The original section is at offset `0x528`, and `.rela.dyn` is at 0x600. Then I copy the contents of `.rela.dyn` at the end of the file; to the offset `0xa528`. I update the section header table entry for `.rela.dyn` by adding `0xa000` to both the `sh_addr` and `sh_offset` fields. I update the `DT_RELA` entry in the dynamic table with the new address; and finally I add a `LOAD` segment (with permissions `RWX`) to the end of the program header table.

As a result, `R_X86_64_RELATIVE` entries in the relocation table are resolved correctly; but the dynamic linker does not update the addresses for external calls in the GOT, therefore causing a segmentation fault. **This does not happen in 32-bit shared objects**.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the .rel.plt table right after the .rel.dyn table. That is, there should not be a single redundant byte in between; no alignment padding, no other sections, no whatever. The dynamic loader expects the relocation segments to be continuous for some reason. The JMPREL entry in the dynamic section seems redundant at x64.